# Javascript to cut same second character on a text

Tags: javascript

For example I have text:

```
var x="default_1305, default_1695, default_1805";
```

I want to cut before the second comma to get this text:"default_1305, default_1695".

How can I do this?

Comment: `x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf(','))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var x="default_1305, default_1695, default_1805";`

string can be split by , like below:

`var res = x.split(",", 2);`

Note 2 here in the second param.

And if needed as string, then

`var res_string = res.join(",");`

---

**Edit**:

[.split() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Syntax

> str.split([separator[, limit]])
>   Parameters

**separator**

> Optional. Specifies the character(s) to use for separating the string. The separator is treated as a string or a regular expression. If separator is omitted, the array returned contains one element consisting of the entire string. If separator is an empty string, str is converted to an array of characters.

**limit**

> Optional. Integer specifying a limit on the number of splits to be found. The split() method still splits on every match of separator, until the number of split items match the limit or the string falls short of separator.

Comment: didn't knew about that second parameter. Thanx

Comment: and `.join(",")` if OP wants the result to be a *string*.

Comment: @ArturFilipiak Good Point!

Answer (score 2):

Convert string to array and get first two elements

```
    var x="default_1305, default_1695, default_1805";
    var b = x.split(',')
    var c = b[0]+","+b[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the parts you need, eg:

```js
// added an extra item to distinguish first-two vs all-but-last
var x="default_1305, default_1695, default_1805, default_1962";

// get first two 
var result = x.split(",").slice(0,2).join(",");
console.log(result);

// get all but last
var result = x.split(",").slice(0,-1).join(",");
console.log(result);
```